# How often do retrotransposons jump in human cells?

Tags: molecular-biology

If I followed the life of a typical cell in my body, how many retrotransposon jumps would I observe per day? I'm only interested in a rough order-of-magnitude estimate: should I think of it as a common event that happens basically all the time in most of my cells, or is it a rare event that happens only occasionally in my body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For just rough order-of-magnitude, try [this reference](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092867400819984). Their experimental design seems to maximize transpositions so it should be a reasonable upper bound.

There is a lot of variability, but some retrotransposons jumped in ~1000 cells per million, others only a few per million such that they were difficult to detect, after about 1 month in HeLa cells.

The same reference gives an estimate of 10,000 retrotransposon elements in a mammalian genome, though, again, their transposition frequencies vary considerably.

Comment: You should also point out that the HeLa genome is incredibly unstable, which could definitely account for some (a lot?) of the activity seen. I haven't had a chance to read the whole paper in detail, but it very well could be that some of the genetic defects in HeLas related to "protecting" the genome and mutational repair are at play here.

Comment: @MattDMo Oh absolutely - I didn't go into specifics but I did mention that their design seems to maximize the transpositions.

Comment: true, I did see that. I just didn't want the OP to think that the numbers were in any way applicable to normal cells. Good answer, though, the paper was interesting.